# Not able to play sound on iphone using JavaScript but able to play on Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, audio, playback

I am trying to play a sound notification on android and iPhone using JavaScript library but I am only able to play the sound on android and not on iPhone.

I am using JavaScript `ion.sound.play("beep")` this function to play the sound. I have kept the sound file in my folder. Can any one help me out; how can I play sound on iPhone using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

The sounds require user input in iOS9. You can initialize the sound with an "invisible" button that disappears after one press at the initialization of your app. Once triggered, you should be able to call ion.sound.play("beep") programatically. I will help You.

CSS:

```
<style>
    #init {
        position: absolute;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
</style>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {

    document.write('<a id="init" ontouchstart="javascript:sndInit();"></a>');

    function sndInit(){
    ion.sound.play("beep");
    ion.sound.pause("beep");
    document.getElementById('init').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks..   I have create a demo in that I am able to hear sound in iphone after clicking on play button. But I want to play on page load without any user input. I have also tried the trigger method for click event in document.ready function but no luck.  Is it possible to play sound on page load?

Comment: Just add this  <audio autoplay>
  <source src="beep.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have tried this but it is only working on desktop not in iphone